# Magento 2: edit order items without cancel

Tags: magento2, sales-order, edit-order

There are many extensions in magneto 2 market place for editing the order info without canceling it.
I know I can edit the shipping and billing info but I don't know how to edit the items quantities and add/remove items. does anyone know how to do it, note that the stock qty needs to be updated accordingly.